# How to get value from an array and echo it in frontend in wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How can i get the value (std) from this array that is located in my theme functions.php

```
    $this->settings['google'] = array(
        'title'   => __( 'Google' ),
        'desc'    => __( 'This is a description for the text input.' ),
        'std'     => 'https://www.google.com/+profile_name',
        'type'    => 'text',
        'section' => 'social'
    );
```

and echo it in my header.php
Tried smth like this and did not work.

```
<li><a href="#" class="social-google">
<?php $google = get_settings['google']['std']; echo $google;?></a></li>
```

Comment: @user2092317 I get this error 
    Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context in header.php

Comment: what is your wordpress version?

Comment: @ChinnuR 3.7.1 latest

Comment: Are you try to use default wordpress get_settings() function right?

Comment: is this piece of code inside a class? and is a part of a function ? the info you provided aint enough to help you

Comment: @pr1nc3 I have added a link to the entire functions.php, please help i am quite a noob in this

Comment: do you have a theme options sub menu  under appearance menu ?  also can you set the google link on that page you are trying to get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); 
?>    

<li><a href="<?php echo  $settings['google']; ?>" class="social-google"></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo  $settings['twitter']; ?>" class="social-twitter"></a></li>

**and so on ...**
```

Answer (score 2):

`$this->settings` calling object variable. Do you define any class in `functions.php`? If yes, then call that class in `header.php` first. If not then there is no `$this` to call.

Do something like this:

```
//functions.php
$settings['google'] = array(...);
global $settings;

//header.php
global $settings;
echo $settings['google']['std'];
```

If you wrapped your `$settings['google'] = array(...);` in function then remember to call `global` at beginning of function.

---

Referring to your comment in your `header.php` file user [`get_option`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) function:

```
$settings = get_option('mytheme_options');
echo $settings['google'];
```

Comment: Could you please have a look at my functions.php http://www.seoadsem.com/test1/functions.txt don't know if there is any class or and how do i call the class, i am kind of a noob

Comment: Code updated. Should work. If not - show me `var_dump(get_option('mytheme_options'));` result.

Comment: No more errors, and it is echowing, but it is echowing only 1 letter, like for example if i input in Social settings in the Google input field http://www.google.com, it only echows h, if i input 123456 it echows 1

Comment: Can you please edit your post and paste there what you got for `var_dump(get_option('mytheme_options'));` ?

Comment: This one i added with your code `$settings=get_option('mytheme_options');
echo $settings['google']['std'];` in header.php?

Comment: `$settings=get_option('mytheme_options'); var_dump($settings);`

Comment: added `<li><a href="<?php $settings = get_option('mytheme_options'); var_dump($settings); ?>" class="social-google"></a></li>` Here is the live version http://www.seoadsem.com/test/blog/